# Adding int and int? in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I ran into a problem, which seems so simple that everyone should have ran into it at some point or another, yet failed to find a solution anywhere.

Copied from the REPL:

```
var a : Int = 1
var c : Int? = 3

a + if (c != null) {c} else {0}
ERROR: None of the following functions can be called with supplied argument (followed by the various implementations of kotlin.int.plus())
```

So what I'm trying to do is add together an Int and an Int? and I'd like the result to be an Int. Very simple. I'm of course aware of the `!!` operator, however I want to avoid using this whenever possible, as it is not change-safe†.

```
a + if (c != null) {c!!} else {0}
4
```

I am aware of the following solution, which handles null-safety and avoids the use of the `!!` operator.

```
a + (c ?: 0)
4
```

My question is the following: Is there a way to do addition with the use of an if-else block and/or a when block, which does not require the use of the `!!` operator. My reason for preferring the use of if-else and not the Elvis operator is intelligibility for people from languages without an Elvis operator. So I'd like to get as close to `a + if (c != null) {c} else {0}` as possible.

Thank you, if my problem or motivation is unclear or contrary to the design or intent of Kotlin, please let me know.

† Sure, I may be able to assert that some variable is safe at the time when it's added, but this assertion will remain there even as code around it changes, possibly making the assertion invalid, thus negating one of Kotlin's points: null safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that kotlin can only assume a variable is never null after a null check if there is no way that variable can change value between operations.

I don't exactly know how the REPL is implemented but my guess is that variables are inserted as members into a context class. This means the compiler cannot assume no changes can happen since another thread might change the value between operations.

So it looks like this feature does not work in the REPL, but the elvis operator is a pretty clean alternative.

Comment: Wow, I actually did not expect this would be a REPL specific problem. The null check does in-fact work when used in a function. So `var d = a + if(c != null) {c} else {0};` does work in a function. I've been using the REPL to test things and find various quirks of Kotlin. I guess I should do that in a proper program instead. Thank you.

Comment: ^^ exactly. There are tons of REPL -specific bugs and problems just because REPL is not involved in a typical production workflow